# Material UI Autocomplete, multiple default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a working material ui auto component that has the following code:

```
     <Autocomplete
              multiple
              options={props.cats}
              defaultValue={editRequest?([props.cats[props.post.category]]):undefined}
              limitTags={2}
```

This works when props.post.category has just one value in props.post.category.

When there are two values such as `34,36` coming in for `props.post.category`, it breaks the page with errors.
In a normal function, I would use .map to loop through the array. This is inside a `defaultValue` so I cant figure out how to assign two default values which are basically

```
props.cats[34] and props.cats[36]
```

In other words, how can a string separated by commas be converted to individual arrays

```
input=> 34,35 (stored in props.category)
array=> [props.cats[34], props.cats[35]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap any `props.post.category` with square bracket, `flat` it then `map`, so you don't have to worry about whenever it is a single value or array of values

```js
console.log([34].flat())
console.log([[35, 36]].flat())
```

```js
const getDefaultValue = () => {
  if (!editRequest) {
    return undefined
  }

  return [props.post.category].flat().map((cat) => props.cats[cat])
}

return (
  <Autocomplete
    multiple
    options={props.cats}
    defaultValue={getDefaultValue()}
    limitTags={2}
  />
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It expects `[props.cats[35],props.cats[36]]`. I am getting some intermediate value cannot be filtered error.  Let me play with this based on your answer.